# Force downcast when programming a custom UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

In the following code:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
    withIdentifier: "MyCell",
    for: indexPath
) as MyTableViewCell  // 'UITableViewCell' is not convertible to 'MyTableViewCell'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?
```

We have the error complaining that `UITableViewCell` is not convertible to a `MyTableViewCell`.

So the compiler suggests to do a force cast:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
    withIdentifier: "MyCell",
    for: indexPath
) as! MyTableViewCell  // ?!?!?!
```

However, that feels ugly.

Is there no alternative to force casting when dealing with `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`? Is this really the most idiomatic way to accomplish this in Swift?

Thanks!

Comment: **You** designed `MyTableViewCell` in Interface Builder. **You** should remember that. If the application crashes in this line it's a design error which should never happen at runtime.

Comment: It's not much different than having IBOutlets defined as vars with !.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this really the most idiomatic way

Absolutely. It's perfectly standard.

You *could* downcast safely like this:

```
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
   withIdentifier: "MyCell",
   for: indexPath
) as? MyTableViewCell {
```

But this is one situation where I don't think that's worth doing, because if this turns out not to be a MyTableViewCell, there's a very real sense in which you *want* to crash.

Comment: Can't the type system be leveraged in a way that would remove the need for any casting in the first place?

Associated types and generics come to mind.

Comment: Actually, I believe that maybe you don't want to crash in some cases. For example, if cell reuse fails or something similar, then the force downcast would fail and it should return a new cell actually. I always go for something like this: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell ?? MyTableViewCell()`.

Comment: @FedericoOjeda `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:forIndexPath:)` returns always a non-optional cell. It will never fail by definition. Non-optional values cannot crash.

Comment: @FedericoOjeda The older `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` (without the index path) can return `nil`. The one with `indexPath` can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
  withIdentifier: "MyCell",
  for: indexPath
) as? MyTableViewCell else {
    // Log an error, or fatalError("Wrong cell type."), etc.
    // or maybe return UITableViewCell()
}
```